# Use different pre-build events for different build configurations in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to use different pre-build events for different build configurations in Visual Studio?
For example, I'd like both a release configuration for a beta & live system and have the relevant app.[type].config get copied to app.config before it is compiled.

At the moment the configuration settings are baked into the .settings file, using the settings from the default app.config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways, depending on your exact situation:

Option 1: Check the $(ConfigurationName) variable in your pre-build script, like so:

```
IF EXISTS $(ProjectDir)app.$(ConfigurationName).config 
    COPY $(ProjectDir)app.$(ConfigurationName).config $(ProjectDir)app.config
```

Option 2: Add a "BeforeCompile" MSBuild target to your project file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
    <!-- MSBuild Script here -->
</Target>
```

Option 3: Use configuration file transformations; [this VSIX plug-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5) adds the web.config transform features to non-web projects. These are XSLT files that let you rewrite your config files on build (unlike web projects, where it happens on publish.)

Answer (score 2):

Or just put the Condition on your target ... eg.,

```
Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"
```

.. or on your task.

If you're using Visual Studio VB/C# simple post build events, you can hand-edit the project file to put such conditions on the PreBuildEvent/PostBuildEvent property tags; and repeat the tags for Release.

Dan (msbuild dev)

Comment: And from this moment on, VS (at lest 2010) will show PostBuild as empty and during compilation the magic will be happening and in big teams this will eventually lead to confusion and lost time. Good solution but potentially dangerous.

Answer (score 2):

To use different build events for different configuration in visual studio, open the cs proj file of the project. in the pre build section

```
<Target Name="PreBuild" BeforeTargets="PreBuildEvent">
    <Exec Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'" Command="echo Release" />
    <Exec Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'" Command="echo Debug" />
  </Target>
```

The command in "Command" parameter will only execute if this condition is met.